# If $ \ \int_{-1}^{3} f(t)=10 \ $ , then find the value of $ \ \int_{0}^{2} [f(2x-1)-x] dx \ $ .

Tags: calculus

If $ \ \int_{-1}^{3} f(t)=10 \ $ , then find the value of $ \ \int_{0}^{2} [f(2x-1)-x] dx \ $ .

**Answer:**

$  \int_{0}^{2} [f(2x-1)-x] dx $

$ =\int_{0}^{2} f(2x-1)dx-\int_{0}^{2} xdx \\ = \int_{0-1/2}^{3-1/2} f(2x) dx -\int_{0}^{2} x dx, \ (By \ subtracting \ the \ shift \ factor \ 1/2 ) \\ = \int_{2 \cdot (-1/2)}^{2 \cdot (3/2)}f(x)dx - \int_{0}^{2} xdx , \ (By \ 2x \to x \ \ and \ thereby \ limit \ change  \ by \ factor \ 2  \ multiplid ) \\ =\int_{-1}^{3} f(x)dx-\int_{0}^{2} xdx \\ =10- [\frac{x^2}{2}]_{0}^{2} , \ (By \ given \ integral ) \\ =10-2 \\ =8 $

**Am I right ? Is there any other method ? Help me**

Comment: Try setting $2x-1=y$

Comment: I tried but I can not match the limits of both integrals. would you help me

Comment: If $ 2x-1=y , then \ \int_{0}^{2} (f(2x-1)-x)dx=\int_{1/2}^{3/2} f(y)dy-\int_{0}^{2} x dx = 1/2 *\int_{1}^{3} f(t)dt-2 , \ (By \ y=t/2) $ . But the lower limit needed to be $ -1 $.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take $u=2x-1$ then 
$$\to \begin{cases}x=0 \to u=2(0)-1 & u=-1\\x=2 \to u=2(2)-1& u=3 \\u=2x-1 \to du=2dx & dx=\frac12 du\end{cases} $$so 
$$=\int_{0}^{2} f(2x-1)dx-\int_{0}^{2} xdx \\ 
= \int_{-1}^{3} f(u) \frac12 du -\int_{0}^{2} x dx \\ = \frac12\int_{-1 }^{3}f(u)du - \int_{0}^{2} xdx \\ =\frac12\int_{-1}^{3} f(x)dx-\int_{0}^{2} xdx \\ =\frac12 \times 10- [\frac{x^2}{2}]_{0}^{2}  \\ =5-2 \\ =3$$